# .htaccess is changing my URL eventhough I'm using [P] flag and relative target

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I have my wordpress site located in a subdirectory as such

domain.com/wordpress

I want visitors to go to domain.com and see my wordpress site, without the URL changing to domain.com/wordpress

I followed some other post on here with same issue, but none of the solutions fixes it for me. Here is my htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$
#RewriteRule ^(/)?$ wordpress [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*) /wordpress [p]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Can you just make the Wordpress directory DocumentRoot?

Comment: How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you don't need `.htaccess` to do this. Through your WordPress dashboard go to:

```
Settings > General
```

And then change these settings: 
[image]

Finally, "Save Changes".